# JFormattedTextField removes fraction part

Tags: java, swing, number-formatting, jformattedtextfield, numberformatter

Whenever I enter any number with a fraction for example 50.25 the fraction part gets removed to 50.00.

```
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00");
NumberFormatter currencyFormatter = new NumberFormatter(decimalFormat);
currencyFormatter.setMinimum(0);

JFormattedTextField AmountField = new JFormattedTextField(currencyFormatter);
```

How can I fix it to accept fraction numbers?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want the JFormattedTextedField to accept values with fraction like 10.25 because now the number gets converted to 10.00 (the fraction part gets removed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing setMinimum value solved the problem:

```
currencyFormatter.setMinimum(0.00);
```